# git head detached from master

Tags: git

Its really confusing i trying push my all commits to production. But when i push to server 8840f9e pushing this.

My goal is **push all my commits** to production.

```
commit d06a8c7(HEAD)

commit e1467b4

commit 0ed15e7

commit 5886ab9

commit 0f8ee01

commit 8840f9e (production/master, master)
```

Comment: Hi @PuresvurenBathishig ! I'm afraid, your question is not clear to me. Could you provide more information on what you tried and what happens? Based on the log, it sounds like you have been creating commits that are on no branch, is that right?

Comment: HI @lucidbrot i really don't know what going on here. When i commit its working and when i push its pushing 8840f9eaa0fbc8eaae592859d3e310bb91697468 this commit.

Comment: You could try `git branch tempbranch d06a8c7d9a && git checkout master && git merge tempbranch` to get the commit onto your master branch, and then do the push to production. Git log is telling you in parantheses that `production/master` and `master` are pointing to the commit `8840f9`. You want `master` to point to your latest commit though.

Comment: What is the output when you run `git branch`? If your problem is what I assume it is, it will be `(HEAD detached from ...)`, is that right?

Comment: @lucidbrot problem solved thanks sir you saved my day.

Comment: I'll explain why it works in an answer, in that case. No problem :) Btw, make sure you read up on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that less questions will be neccessary next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**
You could try `git branch tempbranch d06a8c7d9a && git checkout master && git merge tempbranch` to get the commit onto your master branch, and then do the push to production.

---

Usually, git commits are on some branch. Maybe on multiple, but that's not relevant here.
When you usually work, you are supposed to have some branch checked out - yours is called `master`.
But it can happen that you leave the branch, and create commits of your new changes without telling git on which branch they belong. In that case, git will enter something called a "detached head state".

For example:

```
git init
touch file.txt
git add file.txt
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

Creates a file and commits it. Let us modify the file and commit again, so we have two commits. If you now explicitly `git checkout HEAD~`, i.e. if you check out the first commit, you are no longer on the `master` branch. This is just one example of how to get to that state.

If you now create a new commit, git will warn you:

> ```
> $ git checkout HEAD^
> Note: checking out 'HEAD^'.
>
> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
> changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
> state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
>
> If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
> do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:
>
>   git checkout -b <new-branch-name>
>
> HEAD is now at 24ebade initial commit
> ```

To get the new commits back to some branch, you can do what it recommends you.
Create a new branch which points to your latest commit, using `git checkout -b tempBranch` for example.

It is possible, that you have some commits on `master`, that contradict your changes that happened in this detached HEAD state which is now on `tempBranch`. Because of that, you might need to resolve merge conflicts.

```
git checkout master
git merge tempbranch
```

makes sure both your commit histories are merged together into your `master` branch.
After resolving merge conflicts, you are back at a state which you're used to, and can push as usual.
To clean up, since you do not need the temporary branch `tempBranch` anymore, you can delete it using `git branch -d tempbBranch`.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new temporary branch , say tempcommit
- Checkout new branch
- add commit to new branch
- merge new branch to master

All in one command is like this

```
git branch tempcommit <commit id> && git checkout master && git merge tempbranch
```